# Django 2.2.4 -- Cannot get ORM to mimic the "group by" SQL function with expected results

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a super simple example to show my issues.

```
class TestModel(MyModel):
    # MyModel simply adds a UUID id and created_at/updated_at...

    shape = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, null=False)
    color = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test_model'
```

I put in some content...

```
select * from test_model;

                  id                  |         created_at         | updated_at |   shape   | color 
--------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+-----------+-------
 92a04279-9dd5-40c8-a056-052456df4e56 | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Circle    | Red
 3100ed61-056a-4da1-a537-df32496c658a | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Square    | Blue
 61e2a86a-97ef-4530-a8bb-601411280ff9 | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Heart     | Blue
 3fb19a51-9e10-4214-ad63-22422e2b77f6 | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Hexagon   | Red
 945356ab-d375-4a3b-aafc-e20c5f79f6c3 | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Rectangle | Blue
 96dcfef1-7668-44da-97cc-a86e419d6936 | 2019-12-16 14:44:21.363-05 |            | Trapeze   | Red
```

What I want is simple. I want to know how many shapes of each distinct colors there are. So in SQL I write...

```
select color, count(shape) from test_model group by color;

 color | count 
-------+-------
 Red   |     3
 Blue  |     3
```

Trying to do the same with Django/ORM/Annotate simply does not work, no matter what I try. My last attempt:

```
colors = TestModel.objects.annotate(color_count=Count('color', distinct=True))                                                                                

 for item in colors.all(): 
    print(item.color + " " + str(item.color_count))
```

But I get this...

```
Blue 1
Red 1
Blue 1
Red 1
Blue 1
Red 1
```

What I expect is:

```
Red 3
Blue 3
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `distinct=True` which will result in selecting only **one** of each colors; try this:

```
TestModel.objects.values('color').annotate(count=Count('color'))
```